# How to suppress PC-Lint Note 970 for int main(void) function?

Tags: c, c99, misra, ansi-c, pc-lint

I have a Visual Studio Windows Console application with ANSI C code. The **main** function definition is something like:

```
int main(void)
{
    // do stuff
    return 0;
}
```

However, PC-Lint reports the below message for the **int** type

> Note 970: Use of modifier or type ⁡**int⁢** outside of a typedef [MISRA
>   2012 Directive 4.6, advisory]

I need to keep both the int type for the main function and the Note 970. Therefore, I want to suppress Note 970 just for the main function definition. I don't want to put a //lint !e970 on the source code.

I would like to know if it is possible to suppress this message only for the definition of the main function with PC-Lint options.

Comment: Thanks for yet another chance to shame this buggy tool publicly on the internet. Almost every single MISRA question about Lint comes with the answer "it is a bug in Lint"/"it is a false positive". Maybe if we shame them enough perhaps they will finally get their crap straight. I would recommend using another tool.

Comment: Well, if you want to use PC-Lint for MISRA you will have to add some lint comments in the code. It's inevitable. If you have a main.c you could do something like "lint-nt.exe -esym(970,int) main.c +esym(970,int) file1.c file2.c ...", but it obviously does not scale very well.

Answer (score 6):

Your tool is broken, report a bug to PC Lint.

Quoting MISRA-C:2012 Directive 4.6:

> Exceptions:
>
> For function `main` an *int* may be used rather than the *typedefs* as a return type. Therefore `int main (void)` is permitted.